# Communicating with multiple BLE devices at once

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I read almost every single one thread about BLE on the stackoverflow, nordicsemi devzone, online tutorials etc but still can't solve problem of connecting 10> BLE devices to android in parallel communication. I know that theoretically android limit is 7 so when I write 10 I mean 10 in minimum amount of time.

Setup is standard. Service, GATT for every device, broadcast listeners, leScanCallbacks etc.

Problem occurs when few devices are communicating with android and it occurs on different communication steps.

Cases are like this:

One device is connected and communicating, second also, third one is trying to connect but it keeps failing. After successful connection of teh third one, two new devices are trying to connect but keep failing.

Problem also occurs when few devices are communicating but are on different steps. One is on discovery, second on reading battery level and the third one can't connect until those two finish and disconnect/close.

Sometimes response doesn't come and after programatically set timeout requests retry nothing happens etc

I could write xy failed cases but there wouldn't be pattern which could point out obvious error and that is the main problem. Only thing certain is that some kind of collision exists and "block" response from device to my broadcast receiver but that collision is very odd since android device supports 7 connections at the time and sometimes i don't get response even when <7 devices are communicating simultaneously.

When I set communication to go one after another(when previous disconnects start next) everything goes smoothly but that takes time and time is the main reason I am trying to sync max number of devices asynchronously.

My question is does multiple communicating through bluetooth could work and if it can how to achieve it on android? I saw example of iOS handling it through multiple threads but I don't have the idea how to achieve in android with broadcast receiver so I put communication steps in different threads but it changed nothing.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of how I use BLE threads:
From the main java I start it:

```
uartBluetoothLaser = new UartBluetooth(this, mHandler);
uartBluetoothRF = new UartBluetooth(this, mHandler);
btAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
btAdapter.startLeScan(scanCallback);                                
uartBluetoothLaser.connect(mainActivity,btAdapter,bluetoothDevice);
```

And this is the thread code:

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.UUID;

import com.rsradar.app.MainActivity;
import com.rsradar.app.model.Constants;

public class UartBluetooth {
    private final static String TAG = UartBluetooth.class.getSimpleName();

    private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private String mBluetoothDeviceAddress;
    private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
    private int mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
    private BluetoothDevice device;
    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 2;

    public final static String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED =
            "com.nordicsemi.nrfUART.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
    public final static String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
            "com.nordicsemi.nrfUART.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
    public final static String EXTRA_DATA =
            "com.nordicsemi.nrfUART.EXTRA_DATA";
    public final static String DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART =
            "com.nordicsemi.nrfUART.DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART";


    public static final UUID TX_POWER_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001804-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    public static final UUID TX_POWER_LEVEL_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002a07-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    public static final UUID CCCD = UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    public static final UUID FIRMWARE_REVISON_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002a26-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    public static final UUID DIS_UUID = UUID.fromString("0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    public static final UUID RX_SERVICE_UUID = UUID.fromString("6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e");
    public static final UUID RX_CHAR_UUID = UUID.fromString("6e400002-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e");
    public static final UUID TX_CHAR_UUID = UUID.fromString("6e400003-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e");




    // Debugging
    private static final boolean D = true;

    // Name for the SDP record when creating server socket
    private static final String NAME = "BluetoothMulti";

    // Member fields
    private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private final Handler mHandler;
    private int mState;

    private ArrayList<String> mDeviceAddresses;
    private ArrayList<BluetoothSocket> mSockets;
    /**
     * A bluetooth piconet can support up to 7 connections. This array holds 7 unique UUIDs.
     * When attempting to make a connection, the UUID on the client must match one that the server
     * is listening for. When accepting incoming connections server listens for all 7 UUIDs.
     * When trying to form an outgoing connection, the client tries each UUID one at a time.
     */
    private ArrayList<UUID> mUuids;

    // Constants that indicate the current connection state
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
    //public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
    //public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

    public UartBluetooth(Context context, Handler handler) {
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mState = STATE_NONE;
        mHandler = handler;
        mDeviceAddresses = new ArrayList<String>();
        mSockets = new ArrayList<BluetoothSocket>();
        mUuids = new ArrayList<UUID>();
        // 7 randomly-generated UUIDs. These must match on both server and client.
        mUuids.add(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
        mUuids.add(UUID.fromString("2d64189d-5a2c-4511-a074-77f199fd0834"));
    }

    /**
     * Set the current state of the chat connection
     * @param state  An integer defining the current connection state
     */
    private synchronized void setState(int state) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
        mState = state;

        // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
        mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
    }

    /**
     * Return the current connection state. */
    public synchronized int getState() {
        return mState;
    }

    /**
     * Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
     * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume() */
    public synchronized void start() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "start");

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        //if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

        setState(STATE_LISTEN);
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectThread to initiate a connection to a remote device.
     * @param device  The BluetoothDevice to connect
     */
    public synchronized void connect(MainActivity mainActivity, BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter, BluetoothDevice device) {
        this.mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothAdapter;
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        this.device = device;

        Log.w(TAG, "test on try connect");

        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || device.getAddress() == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
            return;
        }

        Log.w(TAG, "run is running");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(mainActivity, true, mGattCallback);
        }
        mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
    }


    /**
     * Stop all threads
     */
    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "stop");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            if(mBluetoothGatt != null){
                mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
            }
        }
        try {
            this.finalize();
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
        setState(STATE_NONE);
    }



    /**
     * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
     * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted
     * (or until cancelled).
     */

    private BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            String intentAction;

            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                // TODO: handler
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
                // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                            mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());
                }

            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                intentAction = Constants.ACTION_GATT_LASER_DISCONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                // TODO: handler
                mainActivity.btListener.listenerSet(false,device.getName());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                Log.w(TAG, "mBluetoothGatt = " + mBluetoothGatt );
                // TODO: handler
                mainActivity.btListener.listenerSet(true,device.getName());
                enableTXNotification();
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                         BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                         int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                // TODO: handler
                System.out.println(" read ok");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            //System.out.println("RUN");
            // TODO: handler
            byte[] buffer = characteristic.getValue();
            int deviceType = 0;
            if (device.getName().equals(Constants.DEVICE_LASER)){
                deviceType = 1;
            } else if (device.getName().equals(Constants.DEVICE_RF)){
                deviceType = 2;
            }
            mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, deviceType, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
            //System.out.println(" change ok");
        }
    };

    public void enableTXNotification()
    {
        /*
        if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            showMessage("mBluetoothGatt null" + mBluetoothGatt);
            broadcastUpdate(DEVICE_DOES_NOT_SUPPORT_UART);
            return;
        }
            */
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            BluetoothGattService RxService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(RX_SERVICE_UUID);
            if (RxService == null) {
                return;
            }
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic TxChar = RxService.getCharacteristic(TX_CHAR_UUID);
            if (TxChar == null) {
                return;
            }
            mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(TxChar,true);

            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = TxChar.getDescriptor(CCCD);
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
        }

    }

    public void readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
        }
    }
}
```